# Preg replace an array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

i've trying to replace a fetched url that is being piped into an array

this is the original code

```
$res['images'] = array();
$res['images'][] = (string)$item->LargeImage->URL;
if (count($item->ImageSets) > 0) {
$count = 0;
foreach ($item->ImageSets->ImageSet as $key => $value) {
if ($count > 5) continue;
if (isset($value->LargeImage->URL) && $count > 0) {
$res['images'][] = (string)$value->LargeImage->URL;
      }
        $count++;
         }
       }
```

what i need to do is to replace the variable $rest['images'][] or the $item i'm confused, with something like that

```
 $res['images'] = array();
 $res['imagesLow'][] = (string)$item->LargeImage->URL;
 $res['Images'][] = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '._UL1500_.jpg', $res['imagesLow'][]);      
                if (count($item->ImageSets) > 0) {
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($item->ImageSets->ImageSet as $key => $value) {
                        if ($count > 5) continue;
                        if (isset($value->LargeImage->URL) && $count > 0) {
                        $res['images'][] = (string)$value->LargeImage->URL;
                        }
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
```

but this isn't acceptable for the last variable in $res['imagesLow'][] has [] in it.

```
$res['Images'][] = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '._UL1500_.jpg', $res['imagesLow'][]);
```

it gives me error 500
what am i doing wrong?

the main idea it to replace the fetched .JPG part of the url with "*.UL1500*.jpg"

Comment: you can't access the last inserted item of an array in such way. save value  in temporary variable or use `$res['imagesLow'][count(res['imagesLow'])-1]`

Comment: can you provide the whole code fixed?, i'm still learning

Comment: f.e., `$temp = $res['imagesLow'][] = (string)$item->LargeImage->URL;` and use temp in the next statement

Answer (score 0):

The line `$res['imagesLow'][] = (string)$item->LargeImage->URL;` adds a new element to the `$res['imagesLow']` array.

In order to retrieve that value you need the last value of the `$res['imagesLow']` array.

You can get the last value `end($res['imagesLow'])`

However, it would make more sense to use the original variable `(string)$item->LargeImage->URL` again

**Edit**

Replace line:

`$res['Images'][] = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '._UL1500_.jpg', $res['imagesLow'][])`

With:

`$res['Images'][] = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '._UL1500_.jpg', (string)$item->LargeImage->URL);`

Comment: can you please provide the full code with the fix, i'm still on an ongoing learning process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply an function to each element of an array, your normally use `array_map`.

This looks like this

```
$mapped = array_map(function($item) {
    return something with $item;
}, $array);
```

In case of `preg_replace`, you could also just pass the array as subject param. If you pass an array, you also return an array.

```
$res['Images'] = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '._UL1500_.jpg', $res['imagesLow']);
```

Comment: can you please provide the full code with the fix, i'm still on an ongoing learning process